# What's the difference between a "Shape" and a "Placeholder" in Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm trying to delve deeper into the innter-workings of Powerpoint and I'm not fully understanding the difference between [Shapes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape) and [Placeholders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.placeholders). They both seem to be generic objects representing things one can place onto a slide.

Can someone explain a better differentiator to help me understand these two different objects?

Comment: In layman's terms a placeholder is a shape on a master slide that will then appear on all slide in a presentation in such a way that you an click on it and start typing. This causes the formatting (size, font, etc...) and placement of the text to be consistent from one slide to another

Comment: To add a bit to @cybernetic.nomad's comment:  anything on a slide, layout or master is a shape, other than the background fill. A placeholder is a special type of shape that can *contain* other shapes (text, charts, pictures, etc) and control the placement and formatting of the contained shapes.